# Disable touch event handling of an InkCanvas in UWP

Tags: c#, touch, uwp, inkcanvas

I have an InkCanvas over the front of my application.
I want it to only interact with Stylus/Pen events. All other events should be passed through to the various controls underneath the canvas.
The intention is that I detect gestures on the InkCanvas with a pen, while other manipulation events are handled by the controls below the InkCanvas (such as touch and inertial manipulation).

Currently I've tried disabling manipulation events, capturing them, setting handled = false. So far I can't find the right solution. Any ideas?

Comment: *"I can't find the right solution"* - It would help to know, what specifically is wrong with your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect the input mode (`PointerDeviceType`) in the `Pointer` events of the `InkCanvas`, for example:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="400" Height="400" Background="LightBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              PointerPressed="scrollViewer_PointerPressed">
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Height="300" Width="300" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Height="300" Width="300" Fill="Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Width="400" Height="400" GotFocus="inkCanvas_GotFocus" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Tapped="inkCanvas_Tapped" PointerPressed="inkCanvas_PointerPressed"/>
```

code behind:

```
private void inkCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Accept input only from a pen or mouse with the left button pressed.
    PointerDeviceType pointerDevType = e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType;
    if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Pen)
    {
        //TODO:
    }
    else
    {
        // Process touch or mouse input
        inkCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

private void scrollViewer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerDeviceType pointerDevType = e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType;
    if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Pen)
    {
        inkCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        // Process touch or mouse input
        inkCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```